# use of <div> tag inside table rows

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS

My requirement is inside table that my first row should be in different "div" tag and other rows in different div tag. Can anyone explain me how i can do so

```
<table>
      <div> 1st Row </div>
      <div> 2nd Row
            3rd Row
            4rth Row
            5th Row
                    </div>
```

How i can do inside table.

Comment: Rows can't be inside of `div`s

Comment: What have you tried? You may find that google has lots of resources for those starting HTML/CSS. Something to start: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/

Comment: No need for a downvote here on the question. Sometimes we need to lead people to the question they should be asking --- in this case, "How do you group rows in a table together?"

Comment: Why do you need the first row to be different? That might determine the best answer (e.g. if it's a heading, it might be better to use a standard `tr` row but with [`th`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) rather than `td` children, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

No need to use DIV tags. Use `<tbody>` instead:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

A table can have multiple TBODY elements used to group rows together semantically.